# Is there a type of transistor (or other semiconductor device) that can do this?

Tags: transistors, component-selection

I haven't completely given up yet, on using some kind of semiconductor for the boxed ??? device below, to control an ATX power supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6ATtA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[A JFET doesn't work there,](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/622146/53375) but is there something that does?
I'd rather use a normally-closed relay than [the MCU's ESD diodes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/623068/53375), but is there a semiconductor device that can do it instead?

1. It needs to be ON with no power to the circuit at all, so that the PWR_BTN can pull the nATX_EN to ground.
2. As part of the startup init code, the MCU pulls GPIO_0 high, followed by GPIO_2 high, at which point the ??? device should turn OFF.  Now the PWR_BTN becomes an ordinary user button with an internal pull-up on GPIO_1.

To power off, either:

- De-power the MCU, which makes all GPIO's Hi-Z.  The circuit then returns to the normal powered-off state.
- Hold the PWR_BTN long enough to trigger a software timeout.  The MCU then pulls GPIO_2 low, which turns ??? on, followed by GPIO_0 low, and waits to lose power.  Actual power loss happens when the button is released.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137181/discussion-on-question-by-aarond-is-there-a-type-of-transistor-or-other-semicon).

Answer (score 3):

Even though what you ask can probably be achieved with a depletion MOSFET ([like this](https://www.digikey.ie/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/DN3135K1-G/4902754) even if it seems currently unavailable) driven off by a negative voltage somehow generated by the MCU (a charge pump? A small flyback?) all this seems unnecessary complicated.

What about something of the kind instead?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMLcA8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which is what's commonly done for this functionality.

- When MCU is power down D1 prevents voltage on the nATX_EN pin messing up with the MCU itself clamp diodes.
- When pushing PWR_BTN you start the ATX power supply via D2.
- When the MCU is running you can read the PWR_BTN status via D1.
- When the MCU is running you can override nATX_EN by M1

You may  just want to use Schottky diodes for D1 and D2 to have more noise margin on logic low levels.

If I were to produce this I'd also add some RFI/EMI/surge stuff depending on applicable regulations and market.

Comment: Okay, why didn't I think of that?  I guess that's why this site exists.  Thank you!

Comment: And would it be accurate to directly answer the question as asked with, "There isn't such a device, and it's hard to make one from discrete parts."?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsx6eg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As I understood, you want to disable the standard power button function as long as the MCU has control. The MCU must see the power button signal and will react on it, but the ATX supply must not see the signal.

Further more, you will emulate the pressed button by the MCU.

When we assume the MCU is off, Q1 is conducting via R2 base drive if the button is pressed. The emitter voltage will be around 0.6 V and the ATX supply will read this as active button.

The MCU will then set output GPIO_2 to high, which disables the GND path of the button. The small current via R4 is not enough to pull down nATX_EN and the emitter voltage will be above 3.8V via EB of Q1 if the button is pressed. This will not be seen as active by the ATX supply.

Pressing the button now, will turn on M2, which can be seen by input GPIO_1.

One of your requirements is: "De-power the MCU, which makes all GPIO's Hi-Z. The circuit then returns to the normal powered-off state."
This is not the case here, as not in your schematic. The ATX supply will not reach power off state. You need an extra circuit, that emulates the button pressed for a short time, while the MCU already has lost control.